# d3.js how to generate tree hierarchy from csv or table

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tree, hierarchical-data

I have a csv with the following data:

```
world,country,state

World,US,CA

World,US,NJ

World,INDIA,OR

World,INDIA,AP
```

I need to convert in to a tree hierarchy as shown below:

```
{

"name": "World",
"children": [
  { "name": "US",
      "children": [
       { "name": "CA" },
       { "name": "NJ" }
     ]
  },
  { "name": "INDIA",
      "children": [
      { "name": "OR" },
      { "name": "TN" }
     ]
  }
```

]
    };

Using d3.nest I can only get to an json array, not a tree with the name 'children' in it. Anything additional I need to do? Reading API didn't really help, and I can't find a snippet of code that does the conversion anywhere I searched.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Based on your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50033279/7106086), I'm assuming that you want to use this hierarchical data in a d3 hierarchical layout*

Once read by d3.csv/tsv/dsv etc, you get an array with objects like so:

```
[
  { "world": "World","country": "US","state": "CA" },
  { "world": "World","country": "US","state": "NJ" },
  { "world": "World","country": "INDIA","state": "OR" },
  { "world": "World","country": "INDIA","state": "AP"}
]
```

We can use d3 nest to get us most of the way to a usable tree for a d3 hierarchy (tree, dendogram etc) layout:

```
{ 
  "key": "World", "values": [
    {
      "key": "US", "values": [
        { "world": "World", "country": "US", "state": "CA" },
        { "world": "World", "country": "US", "state": "NJ" }
      ]
    },
    {
      "key": "INDIA", "values": [
        { "world": "World", "country": "INDIA", "state": "OR" }, 
        { "world": "World", "country": "INDIA", "state": "AP" }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This was made with:

```
var nestedData = d3.nest()
 .key(function(d) { return d.world; })
 .key(function(d) { return d.country; })
 .entries(data);
```

*This produces an array, with each item in the array being a root. To get the json above with d3.nest() we need to get the first element in the array, in this case, `nestedData[0];`. Also note we generally don't need to nest the lowest level, in this case the state*

Now we can feed this data to [d3.hierarchy](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy#hierarchy) to get a hierarchy to use for visualizations. If you look at the documentation we have an identical data structure to the example, except our children are contained in a property called "values" rather than "children". No worry, d3.hierarchy allows us to set the name of the property that holds the children:

> **d3.hierarchy(data[, children])**
>
> ...
>
> The specified children accessor function is invoked for each datum,
>   starting with the root data, and must return an array of data
>   representing the children, or null if the current datum has no
>   children. If children is not specified, it defaults to:
>
> `function children(d) {   return d.children; }`

So, to take the above data created from d3.nest, let's feed it to d3.hierarchy:

```
var root = d3.hierarchy(nestedData[0],function(d) { return d.values; })
```

Now we have a dataset that can be fed to any d3 hierarchical layout:

```js
var data = [
 { "world": "World","country": "US","state": "CA" }, 
 { "world": "World","country": "US","state": "NJ" },
 { "world": "World","country": "INDIA","state": "OR" },
 { "world": "World","country": "INDIA","state": "AP"}
];

 
var nestedData = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d.world; })
  .key(function(d) { return d.country; })
  .entries(data);
 
var root = d3.hierarchy(nestedData[0], function(d) { return d.values; })

// Now draw the tree:

var width = 500;
var height = 400;

margin = {left: 10, top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10}

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);
   
var g = svg.append("g").attr('transform','translate('+ margin.left +','+ margin.right +')');

   
var tree = d3.tree()
    .size([height-margin.top-margin.bottom,width-margin.left-margin.right]);

 var link = g.selectAll(".link")
    .data(tree(root).links())
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", d3.linkHorizontal()
          .x(function(d) { return d.y; })
          .y(function(d) { return d.x; }));

  var node = g.selectAll(".node")
    .data(root.descendants())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return "node" + (d.children ? " node--internal" : " node--leaf"); })
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; })

  node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 2.5);
   
  node.append("text")
     .text(function(d) { return d.data.key; })
  .attr('y',-10)
  .attr('x',-10)
  .attr('text-anchor','middle');
```

```css
path {
  fill:none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

[Here's an example](http://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/7ae1657ba0426683585cd18a0e002f62) with an actual csv and a few more rows and levels.

---

If the csv data structure was different, containing parent, child pairs, then it will look something like this once parsed with d3.csv/tsv/dsv:

```
[
 {parent: "", name: "World"},
 {parent: "World", name:"US"},
 {parent: "World", name:"India"},
 {parent: "India", name:"OR" },
 {parent: "India", name:"AP" },
 {parent: "US", name:"CA" },
 {parent: "US", name:"WA" }
]
```

With this we can use `d3.stratify` instead of the combination of `d3.nest`  and `d3.hierarchy`:

```js
var data = [
 {parent: "", name: "World"},
 {parent: "World", name:"US"},
 {parent: "World", name:"India"},
 {parent: "India", name:"OR" },
 {parent: "India", name:"AP" },
 {parent: "US", name:"CA" },
 {parent: "US", name:"WA" }
];

// manipulate data:

var root = d3.stratify()
  .id(function(d) { return d.name; })
  .parentId(function(d) { return d.parent; })
  (data);
  
// Now draw the tree:

var width = 500;
var height = 400;

margin = {left: 10, top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10}

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);
   
var g = svg.append("g").attr('transform','translate('+ margin.left +','+ margin.right +')');

   
var tree = d3.tree()
    .size([height-margin.top-margin.bottom,width-margin.left-margin.right]);

 var link = g.selectAll(".link")
    .data(tree(root).links())
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", d3.linkHorizontal()
          .x(function(d) { return d.y; })
          .y(function(d) { return d.x; }));

  var node = g.selectAll(".node")
    .data(root.descendants())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return "node" + (d.children ? " node--internal" : " node--leaf"); })
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; })

  node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 2.5);
   
  node.append("text")
     .text(function(d) { return d.data.name; })
  .attr('y',-10)
  .attr('x',-10)
  .attr('text-anchor','middle');
```

```css
path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your thorough and clear answers! is there a way to view the hierarchy data with children structure or export it to a json file? Using inspect, i can see array like this data: ▾Object {
  key: "World"
  values: ▾Array(2) [
  0: ▾Object {
  key: "US"
  values: ▾Array(2) [
  0: ▾Object {
  world: "World"
  country: "US"
  state: "CA"
}
  1: ▸Object {world: "World", country: "US", state: "NJ"}

Comment: You can view the hierarchy with a console.log() statement in browser, but copying to JSON might be a challenge as there is a lot of cyclic references to objects within the hierarchy. Not sure if there is a way to do this to be honest (and if there is, if it would still work in a d3 hierarchical layout)

Comment: pardon my newbie questions. I was able to pass the hierarchy to a tree diagram but still unable to use it for a treemap. Anything amiss? http://jsbin.com/xequpikomi/edit?html,output

Comment: There are just two things that I see, since it doesn't really fit in a comment, see [here](https://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/0ad13f7a4cfdb498a46e982488f067ea).

Comment: Glad I could be helpful