# How to generate JSON from a pandas data frame for dynamic d3.js tree

Tags: python, django, pandas, dataframe, d3.js

I'm new to Pandas and have a complex requirement.

I have a data frame, which contains multiple columns like the one below

```
Parent                            Child      Color
IT;Programming;Trending;Demand    Python     #6200ea
IT;Programming;Trending;Demand    Docker     #7c4dff
IT;Programming;Testing            Selenium   #b388ff
IT;Programming;Old                C/C++/C#   #ff1744
IT-Tools;Testing                  HP UFT     #aa00ff
IT-Tools;IDE                      PyCharm    #9c27b0
```

I've used str.split(';') to generate multiple Parent columns in the data frame

```
df = df.join(df.Parent.str.split(";", expand=True).add_prefix('branch'))
df.drop(columns=['Parent'], inplace=True)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
branch0    branch1        branch2    branch3   Child      Color
IT         Programming    Trending   Demand    Python     #6200ea
IT         Programming    Trending   Demand    Docker     #7c4dff
IT         Programming    Testing    None      Selenium   #b388ff
IT         Programming    Old        None      C/C++/C#   #ff1744
IT-Tools   Testing        None       None      HP UFT     #aa00ff
IT-Tools   IDE            None       None      PyCharm    #9c27b0
```

I need to generate a classification tree for which I need to generate a JSON (along with color value) which is mentioned on the below website

https://bl.ocks.org/swayvil/b86f8d4941bdfcbfff8f69619cd2f460#data-example.json

Can somebody please help me
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your data needs updates for a d3 tree:

- A d3 tree needs a single root node - `IT` and `IT-Tools` need a parent node
- The `Testing` node is ambiguous as it is both a child of `Programming` and `IT-Tools` - so you will need update e.g. `Testing1` and `Testing2`

Your 2nd data frame shows your hierarchy is [unbalanced](https://www.google.com/search?q=unbalanced%20hierarchy) (leaves at different depths) because of the `None`s in `branch2` and `branch3`. Therefore, your output JSON should be individual branch definitions, rather than multiple definitions per row, like this:

```
parent,child,color
IT,Programming,None
Programming,Trending,None
Trending,Demand,None
Demand,Python,#6200ea
etc
```

This is more efficient than multiple-branches-per-row which has redundancy. E.g. `IT` being the parent of `Programming` is defined multiple times whereas with the parent/ child structure it is defined a single time.

The following code translates your input to an output you can send as a response to a client and then use d3 to build a tree.

We can use a set to store unique strings of pairs of parents and then add an item for the last parent/ child. Then create another dataframe from this set (creating columns based on split by `;` in a similar vein to your OP) and then export as JSON:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

# data as a string
text = '''Parent Child Color
IT;Programming;Trending;Demand    Python     #6200ea
IT;Programming;Trending;Demand    Docker     #7c4dff
IT;Programming;Testing1           Selenium   #b388ff
IT;Programming;Old                C/C++/C#   #ff1744
IT-Tools;Testing2                 HP-UFT     #aa00ff
IT-Tools;IDE                      PyCharm    #9c27b0'''

# your original data frame
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), sep=r'\s+')

# prepend a Root to Parent column
df.Parent = 'Root;' + df.Parent

# dataframe to set for unique branches
# start with just root in the set
branch_strings = set([';Root;'])
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  parents = row.Parent.split(';')
  for curr, next in zip(parents, parents[1:]):
    branch_strings.add(';'.join([curr, next, '']))
  branch_strings.add(';'.join([next, row.Child, row.Color]))

# set to list
branches = list(map(lambda row: row.split(';'), branch_strings))

# new dataframe from relations
df2 = pd.DataFrame(branches, columns=['parent', 'child', 'color'])

# JSON
json = df2.to_json(orient='records')
print(json)
```

Which produces this JSON output:

```
const data = [
  {"parent":"Programming","child":"Old","color":""},
  {"parent":"Testing1","child":"Selenium","color":"#b388ff"},
  {"parent":"","child":"Root","color":""},{"parent":"IT-Tools","child":"IDE","color":""},
  {"parent":"IDE","child":"PyCharm","color":"#9c27b0"},
  {"parent":"Programming","child":"Trending","color":""},
  {"parent":"IT","child":"Programming","color":""},
  {"parent":"Trending","child":"Demand","color":""},
  {"parent":"Root","child":"IT","color":""},
  {"parent":"Old","child":"C\/C++\/C#","color":"#ff1744"},
  {"parent":"Programming","child":"Testing1","color":""},
  {"parent":"Root","child":"IT-Tools","color":""},{"parent":"IT-Tools","child":"Testing2","color":""},
  {"parent":"Demand","child":"Docker","color":"#7c4dff"},
  {"parent":"Demand","child":"Python","color":"#6200ea"},
  {"parent":"Testing2","child":"HP-UFT","color":"#aa00ff"}
];
```

For a D3 example with that JSON - please review the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50046169/d3-js-how-to-generate-tree-hierarchy-from-csv-or-table). The adaptaion below is just a proof of concept for your unbalanced hierarchy input. To convert to the block in your OP is beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow answer but this should put you in the right direction:

```js
const data = [
  {"parent":"Programming","child":"Old","color":""},
  {"parent":"Testing1","child":"Selenium","color":"#b388ff"},
  {"parent":"","child":"Root","color":""},{"parent":"IT-Tools","child":"IDE","color":""},
  {"parent":"IDE","child":"PyCharm","color":"#9c27b0"},
  {"parent":"Programming","child":"Trending","color":""},
  {"parent":"IT","child":"Programming","color":""},
  {"parent":"Trending","child":"Demand","color":""},
  {"parent":"Root","child":"IT","color":""},
  {"parent":"Old","child":"C\/C++\/C#","color":"#ff1744"},
  {"parent":"Programming","child":"Testing1","color":""},
  {"parent":"Root","child":"IT-Tools","color":""},{"parent":"IT-Tools","child":"Testing2","color":""},
  {"parent":"Demand","child":"Docker","color":"#7c4dff"},
  {"parent":"Demand","child":"Python","color":"#6200ea"},
  {"parent":"Testing2","child":"HP-UFT","color":"#aa00ff"}
];

const root = d3.stratify()
  .id(d => d["child"])
  .parentId(d => d["parent"])
  (data);

const margin = {left: 40, top: 40, right: 40, bottom: 40}
const width = 500;
const height = 200;
const svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);
      
const g = svg.append("g")
  .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left},${ margin.right})`);

const tree = d3.tree()
  .size([height-margin.top-margin.bottom,width-margin.left-margin.right]);

const link = g.selectAll(".link")
  .data(tree(root).links())
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("class", "link")
  .attr("d", d3.linkHorizontal()
    .x(function(d) { return d.y; })
    .y(function(d) { return d.x; })
  );

const node = g.selectAll(".node")
  .data(root.descendants())
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", function(d) { 
    return `translate(${d.y},${d.x})`; 
  });

node.append("circle")
  .attr("r", 5)
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return d.data.color ? d.data.color : "#000";
  });
      
node.append("text")
  .attr("class", "label")
  .text(function(d) { return d.data.child; })
  .attr('y', -4)
  .attr('x', 0)
  .attr('text-anchor','middle');
```

```css
path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}

.label {
  font-size: smaller;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Yes, a common parent for IT and IT-Tools is there. However, as per my requirement, the number of columns is not fixed which is giving Nones' in many columns.

Comment: Yes, I am working on the assumption that your input will sometimes, if not always, an unbalanced hierarchy with leaves at different depths. Also you say the columns are not fixed - then you have the additional factor of an unknown maximum depth. In this case it is preferable to describe the hierarchy as a parent/ child list (with additional attributes like color) and pass it to D3 and use the `.stratify` function to construct the hierarchy for visualisation. The python code will accept as much depth as there are semicolons in the Parent column and skips the `None` issue